# How to check if datetime happens to be Saturday or Sunday in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Given a `datetime`, is there a way we can know it happens to be a `Saturday` or `Sunday`.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Many ways to do this, you can use DATENAME and check for the actual strings 'Saturday' or 'Sunday'

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())
```

Or use the day of the week and check for 1 (Sunday) or 7 (Saturday)

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Be careful because of @@DATEFIRST (see below answer) https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: Attention: Use `SET DATEFIRST 7` to ensure this works outside US systems!

Comment: Note that `SET DATEFIRST` does not work in table view functions - in such cases used Thanasis' answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49409121/1867581

Answer (score 25):

This expression

```
SELECT (((DATEPART(DW, @my_date_var) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7)
```

will always return a number between 0 and 6 where

```
0 -> Sunday
1 -> Monday
2 -> Tuesday
3 -> Wednesday
4 -> Thursday
5 -> Friday
6 -> Saturday
```

Irrespectively of `@@DATEFIRST`

So a weekend day is tested like this

```
SELECT (CASE
           WHEN (((DATEPART(DW, @my_date_var) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) IN (0,6)
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END) AS is_weekend_day
```

Answer (score 18):

```
DECLARE @dayNumber INT;
SET @dayNumber = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE());

--Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7.
IF(@dayNumber = 1 OR @dayNumber = 7) 
    PRINT 'Weekend';
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT Weekend';
```

This may generate wrong results, because the number produced by the weekday datepart depends on the value set by SET DATEFIRST. This sets the first day of the week. 
So another way is:

```
DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9);
SET @dayName = DATEName(DW, GETDATE());

IF(@dayName = 'Saturday' OR @dayName = 'Sunday') 
    PRINT 'Weekend';
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT Weekend';
```

Answer (score 8):

`SELECT DATENAME(weekday, GetDate())`

Check this for sql server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174395(v=sql.90).aspx
Check this for .net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This will get you the name of the day:

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Short, sweet and self explanatory.

Answer (score 5):

**Attention:** The other answers only work on SQL Servers with English configuration! Use `SET DATEFIRST 7` to ensure `DATEPART(DW, ...)` returns 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday.

Here's a version that is independent of the local setting and does not require to use :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fct_IsDateWeekend] ( @date DATETIME )
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, @date + @@DATEFIRST - 1) > 5  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END;
```

If you don't want to use the function, simply use this in your SELECT statement:

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, YourDateTime + @@DATEFIRST - 1) > 5  THEN 'Weekend' ELSE 'Weekday' END
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i figure out :

```
DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9), @weekenda VARCHAR(9), @free INT
SET @weekenda =DATENAME(dw,GETDATE())

IF (@weekenda='Saturday' OR @weekenda='Sunday')
SET @free=1
ELSE
SET @free=0
```

than i use :  .......... OR free=1

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9);
SET @dayName = DATEName(DW, GETDATE());

IF(@dayName = 'Saturday' OR @dayName = 'Sunday')
PRINT 'Weekend';
ELSE
PRINT 'NOT Weekend';

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))) ,@EndDate DateTime = '2023-02-30 00:00:00.000';
WITH CTE(date_list) AS (
    SELECT @StartDate 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,date_list) FROM CTE
    WHERE date_list <= @EndDate
)

SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,date_list) as 'Day',date_list as 'Date', DATENAME(MONTH,date_list) as 'Month',DATENAME(YEAR,date_list) as 'Year',DATENAME(WEEKDAY,date_list) as 'Holiday_Type'
INTO HolidayMaster
FROM CTE
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,date_list) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
ORDER BY date_list asc;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.