# How to increment date using previous value from same column and skip weekend date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to increment date based on other date column and skip weekend date.

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) -- Friday
SELECT DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) -- 6
```

I know how to check weekend and how to skip date but I want to result as look like below

EX. If I will input date in one column like

```
OriginalDate    
4 October 2019 
5 October 2019
6 October 2019
7 October 2019
8 October 2019
9 October 2019
10 October 2019
11 October 2019
12 October 2019
```

then I want result in new column like

```
OriginalDate        UpdatedDate
4 October 2019      4 October 2019 
5 October 2019      7 October 2019 (skip weekend)
6 October 2019      8 October 2019
7 October 2019      9 October 2019
8 October 2019      10 October 2019
9 October 2019      11 October 2019
10 October 2019     14 October 2019 (skip weekend)
11 October 2019     15 October 2019
12 October 2019     16 October 2019
```

NOTE: don't skip any row from input date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if datetime happens to be Saturday or Sunday in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570087/how-to-check-if-datetime-happens-to-be-saturday-or-sunday-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @xXx i really don't want to know how to check weekend and how to retrieve weekend day or name. i have already tried with that but i want to result as describe in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems quite tricky.  I think my best advice is to reconstruct the data.  A relatively simple method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select min(originaldate) as dte, count(*) as cnt, min(originaldate) as originaldate
      from t
      union all
      select (case when datename(weekday, v.nextdate) = 'Saturday' then dateadd(day, 2, nextdate)
                   when datename(weekday, v.nextdate) = 'Sunday' then dateadd(day, 1, nextdate)
                   else v.nextdate
              end),
             cnt - 1, dateadd(day, 1, originaldate)

      from cte cross apply
           (values (dateadd(day, 1, dte))) v(nextdate)
      where cnt > 0
     )
select originaldate, dte
from cte
order by originaldate;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0aaf448e23c48e39cf4a79f46cc0e945) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  FORMAT(OriginalDate, 'dd MMMM yyyy')
FROM    dbo.TableName WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE   DATENAME(DW, OriginalDate) NOT IN ( 'Sunday', 'Saturday' )
```

Comment: I don't want to skip row of Saturday and Sunday

Answer (score 0):

I created a calendar table to hold dates and an "isweekend" flag, then by excluding the weekend dates and ordering the two tables you can join them together to get the data you need

```
use tempdb
GO

-- create a calendar table
drop table if exists #calendar
GO

CREATE TABLE #calendar(
    [date] date
    , isweekend AS (IiF((datename(weekday,[date])) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday'), 1, 0))
)
--populate with data from 2000 onwards (100000 days)
; with numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as n from sys.columns o1
    cross join sys.columns o2
)
insert into #calendar ([date]) 
select dateadd(day, numbers.n -1, '20000101') from numbers
where numbers.n < 100000
go

drop table if exists #originaldate
GO

create table #originaldate (
    original date
)
GO
insert into #originaldate (original)
values ('20191004'), ('20191005'), ('20191006'), ('20191007'), ('20191008'), ('20191009'), ('20191010'), ('20191011'), ('20191012'), ('20191013')

select * from #originaldate

GO


; with weekdays as ( -- we only want weekdays, in date order
    select [date], row_number() over (order by [date] asc) as rn
    from #calendar c
    where  c.isweekend = 0
    and date >= '20191004' -- IMPORTANT, you must start row number at the same date as the table you want to match againt
)
, originals as ( -- order the dates we are matching
    select original, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [original] asc) as rn
    from #originaldate
)
select o.original, w.date as updateddate
from weekdays w
inner join originals o
on o.rn = w.rn
order by o.original ASC
```